# app naming in the config file Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, config

I keep seeing two different config file naming conventions.  One with an app name explicitly stated and another without (the default).

```
SomeApp::Application.configure do
SomeApp::Application.config.assets.precompile += %w( someManifest.css.scss )
```

but the default is this

```
Rails.application.configure do
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( someManifest.css.scss )
```

Is there a difference?  The default seems to work...so why is the other option there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recent change to Rails. Older versions of Rails would use the app name, but in Rails 4, it uses the `Rails.application` version. If you're seeing a Rails4 app that's using the app name version, it was probably upgraded from Rails 3.

It's best to stick with convention, and use what is default with the version of Rails you're using. If that's 4, then use the `Rails.application` version.